# Capturing python re.compile() with re.DEBUG flag terminal output

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, output, python-re

When using `re.compile()` with the `re.DEBUG` flag, the parse information is printed to the console.
For example, running `pattern = re.compile(r'[ab]+', re.DEBUG)` you get the following output printed in the console:

```py
MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
  IN
    LITERAL 97
    LITERAL 98
```

I want to get this parse tree and keep it in a variable so I can process it, however I don't find where this output is saved if at all.

Note: I am able to get the output by running the compile as a subprocess and capturing the output with

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", "import re; re.compile(r'[ab]+', re.DEBUG)"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()[0]
```

But it feels a bit of an overkill.

Is there any simpler way of getting the debug output?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging and reversing the re lib code, found a rather simple way to get this data.
The re library uses the sre_parse library, you can parse with

```py
p = sre_parse.parse('[ab]+')
```

and retrieve the parse data with

```py
p.data
```

and print it in a tree format with

```py
p.dump()
```